# How to retrieve custom attribute set ID by name

Tags: magento-2.1, programmatically, attribute-set

I have created couple of custom **Attribute Set** and now I want to assign a group in those attribute sets programmatically, so is there any way to retrieve attribute set IDs based on name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can retrieve attribute set ID by using following code:

```
protected $_attributeSetCollection;

public function __construct(
     ...
     ,\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $attributeSetCollection
)
    {
        ...
        $this->_attributeSetCollection = $attributeSetCollection;
    }


public function getAttrSetId($attrSetName)
    {
        $attributeSet = $this->_attributeSetCollection->create()->addFieldToSelect(
                    '*'
                    )->addFieldToFilter(
                            'attribute_set_name',
                            $attrSetName
                    );
        $attributeSetId = 0;
        foreach($attributeSet as $attr):
            $attributeSetId = $attr->getAttributeSetId();
        endforeach;
        return $attributeSetId;
    }
```

You can call **getAttrSetId** method by passing the attribute set name for which you want to retrieve attribute set ID.
eg. `$this->getAttrSetId("YourAttributeSetName");`

Comment: you can reduce response size with select 'attribute_set_id' instead of '*' and avoid a loop on the object with combine getFirstItem and toArray methods. See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/214278/24845

Comment: You should also add ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', 4) so the correct attribute_set_id for "product" is returned.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [Rizwan Dhuka](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50758/rizwan-dhuka) answer, you can:

- reduce response size with select `'attribute_set_id'` instead of `'*'`
- avoid a loop on the object with combine `getFirstItem` and `toArray` methods

  ```
  namespace Nolwennig\CustomCatalog;

  use \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory;

  class CustomProduct
  {

    protected $_attributeSetCollection;

    /**
     *
     * ...
     * @param AttributeSetCollectionFactory $attributeSetCollection
     */
    public function __construct(..., CollectionFactory $attributeSetCollection)
    {
      ...
      $this->_attributeSetCollection = $attributeSetCollection;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $attributeSetName
     * @return int attributeSetId
     */
    public function getAttributeSetId($attributeSetName)
    {
      $attributeSetCollection = $this->_attributeSetCollection->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
        ->getFirstItem()
        ->toArray();

      $attributeSetId = (int) $attributeSetCollection['attribute_set_id'];
      // OR (see benchmark below for make your choice)
      $attributeSetId = (int) implode($attributeSetCollection);

      return $attributeSetId
    }
  }
  ```

---

## Quick (n' dirty?) benchmarks

> - `$attributeSetId = (int) implode($attributeSetCollection);`
>
>   ```
>   .------------------------------------------------------------. 
>   | Version   | System time (s) | User time (s) | Memory (MiB) |
>   |-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------|
>   |    7.2    |      0.035      |     0.012     |     17.96    |
>   |    7.1    |      0.050      |     0.012     |     20.98    |
>   |    hhvm   |      0.088      |     0.234     |     88.93    |
>   |    5.6    |      0.017      |     0.061     |     20.59    |
>   '------------------------------------------------------------'
>   ```
>
>   *[source: 3v4l.org/uRTNh](https://3v4l.org/uRTNh/perf#output)*
>
> ---
>
> - `$attributeSetId = $attributeSetCollection['attribute_set_id'];`
>
>   ```
>   .------------------------------------------------------------. 
>   | Version   | System time (s) | User time (s) | Memory (MiB) |
>   |-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------|
>   |    7.2    |      0.128      |     0.011     |     17.55    | 
>   |    7.1    |      0.131      |     0.011     |     20.86    | 
>   |    hhvm   |      0.100      |     0.204     |     88.75    | 
>   |    5.6    |      0.017      |     0.060     |     20.64    | 
>   '------------------------------------------------------------'
>   ```
>
> *[source: 3v4l.org/8Yq6j](https://3v4l.org/8Yq6j/perf#output)*